# Order by key in multiple arrays

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a calendar (with WordPress). All work fine. But I can't seem to order the events by the hour.

### Actually the output is :

```
Array (
    [2020] => Array (
        [October] => Array (
            [21] => Array (
                [18] => Array (
    
                )
                [14] => Array (
    
                )
                [12] => Array (
    
                )
            )
        )
    [2021] => Array (
        [January] => Array (
            [12] => Array (
                [14] => Array (
    
                )
                [13] => Array (
    
                )
                [11] => Array (
    
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

### I'm trying to get :

```
Array (
    [2020] => Array (
        [October] => Array (
            [21] => Array (
                [12] => Array (
    
                )
                [14] => Array (
    
                )
                [18] => Array (
    
                )
            )
        )
    [2021] => Array (
        [January] => Array (
            [12] => Array (
                [11] => Array (
    
                )
                [13] => Array (
    
                )
                [14] => Array (
    
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

My array is structured like that :

```
[$year]
    [$month]
        [$day]
            [$hour]
```

**How can I order `[$hour]` inside `[$day]` please ?**

```
    $events_list = array();
    
    if($events) {
        foreach($events as $event) {
            $date = $date_event = get_field('event_date', $event->ID, false);
            $hour = $hour_start = get_field('event_hour_start', $event->ID, false);
            $hour_end = get_field('event_hour_end', $event->ID, false);
    
            $date = new DateTime($date);
            $hour = new DateTime($hour);
    
            $date_event = $date->format('l j F');
    
            $year = $date->format('Y');
            $month = $date->format('F');
            $day = $date->format('d');
            $hour = $hour->format('G');
    
            $events_list[$year][$month][$day][$hour] = array('datas'=>$event, 'date'=>$date_event, 'hour_start'=>$hour_start, 'hour_end'=>$hour_end);
        }
    }

ksort($events_list);
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to do this type of sorting at the database level

Comment: [**Read the manual**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: @Martin I read it and tried to use `ksort` without success

Comment: @Jandon please edit your question and state this as well as showing how you tried to use `ksort`. That helps us to help you. Cheers

Comment: is `$hour_start` an array? It looks like you're trying to sort a string!

Comment: Okay @Martin I updated my question. I tried to use `ksort` inside and outside the `foreach`

Answer (score 4):

Use `ksort()`, [read more about it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).
**MWE** (Minimal Working Example) for your use-case would be:

```
$arr = array(
    2021 => array(
        "October" => array(
            21 => array(
                18 => array(),
                14 => array(),
                12 => array()
            )
        )
   )
);

ksort($arr[2021]["October"][21]);
print_r($arr);

// $arr = array(
//    2021 => array(
//        "October" => array(
//            21 => array(
//                12 => array(),
//                14 => array(),
//                18 => array()
//            )
//        )
//    )
// );
```

There is also second optional parameter to this function named `sort_flags`, which can occupy one of the next options:

```
SORT_REGULAR       - compare items normally; the details are described in the comparison operators section. This is DEFAULT value
SORT_NUMERIC       - compare items numerically
SORT_STRING        - compare items as strings
SORT_LOCALE_STRING - compare items as strings, based on the current locale. It uses the locale, which can be changed using setlocale()
SORT_NATURAL       - compare items as strings using "natural ordering" like natsort()
SORT_FLAG_CASE     - can be combined (bitwise OR) with SORT_STRING or SORT_NATURAL to sort strings case-insensitively
```

*edit: will also work on string keys representing the integer values.*

Answer (score 1):

[**Read the Documentation**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

This shows that you can use [**`ksort()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) to sort by the key value of the array.

Therefore, to sort the hour of the array's you can do this with just one line; this wills sort all values of each `$day` array into natural sorting from low to high;

```
ksort($events[$year][$month][$day],SORT_NATURAL);
```

A full example with sample data:

```
$events = [];
$year = date("Y");
$month = date("F");
$day = date("d");
$hour = array('18','10','12','09');

foreach($hour as &$row){
    $events[$year][$month][$day][$row] = mt_rand(0,222);    
        $events[$year][$month][$day][$row] = mt_rand(333,666);
            $events[$year][$month][$day][$row] = mt_rand(7777,9999);
            
    $events[$year][$month][$day+1][$row] = mt_rand(0,222);    
        $events[$year][$month][$day+1][$row] = mt_rand(333,666);
            $events[$year][$month][$day+1][$row] = mt_rand(7777,9999);
}
unset($row);

// before sorting
print_R($events);

foreach($events[$year][$month] as &$day){
    // sorts all hours inside all days in the array. 
    ksort($day);
}


// after sorting.
print_R($events);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help